# RecyclerView "cannot resolve symbol" errors - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am getting cannot resolve symbol errors on all my RecyclerView's.  What is going on?  Because I have an error with RecyclerView, I also have errors on LayoutManager.  My last four Override statements are in the wrong place and I don't know where they go.  I am a beginner and have a very basic knowledge of programming so I don't know how to fix this.  I am taking a class but the professor isn't helpful at all.

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;


public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mCrimeRecyclerView;
    private CrimeAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false);

        mCrimeRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);
        mCrimeRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI(){
        CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
        List<Crime> crimes = crimeLab.getCrimes();

        if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new CrimeAdapter(crimes);
            mCrimeRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
        private class CrimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CrimeHolder> {
            private List<Crime> mCrimes;
            public CrimeAdapter(List<Crime> crimes) {
                mCrimes = crimes;
            }
        }
        private class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
                implements View.OnClickListener {
            private TextView mTitleTextView;
            private TextView mDateTextView;
            private CheckBox mSolvedCheckBox;
            private Crime mCrime;

            public CrimeHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                mTitleTextView = (TextView)
                        itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_crime_title_text_view);
                mDateTextView = (TextView)
                        itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_crime_date_text_view);
                mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)
                        itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_crime_solved_check_box);
            }

            public void bindCrime(Crime crime) {
                mCrime = crime;
                mTitleTextView.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
                mDateTextView.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
                mSolvedCheckBox.setChecked(mCrime.isSolved());
            }

            @Override
            public CrimeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
                View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false);
                return new CrimeHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(CrimeHolder holder, int position) {
                Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
                holder.bindCrime(crime);
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                return mCrimes.size();
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = CrimeActivity.newIntent(getActivity(), mCrime.getId());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: check your dependencies should have something like : `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:xx.x.x'` - x's for version

Comment: That should go in my library dependency?

Comment: Yes, at module level. Check version other android dependencies version, should be something like '24.2.1' and match it.

Comment: @rpach17 If after adding this dependency `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'` you are getting the same error then restart your Android Studio as this might happen due to improper indexing.

Answer (score 23):

These are your import statements,

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;
```

Looks like you haven't imported `RecyclerView`, `LayoutManager` and anything which you are using inbuilt in Android. You just need to import the classes that you are seeing red lines under.

`How to Import?`

Press `alt + Enter` on windows, or `alt + return` on mac to import. You should have your cursor at the end of class.

If you haven't imported library, then add this to `build.gradle` file under dependancies.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

Update :

Latest recycler library is this :

1. With latest gradle version. 3.0 or above.

   ```
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
   ```
2. with old gradle version

   ```
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
   ```

Update:
latest Androidx Jetpack dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0"
}
```

source : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview

Comment: The imports have a red line under RecyclerView and LayoutManager

Comment: updated answer, try adding library, and rebuild the project.

Comment: did you clean and rebuild the project? , and if yes, then let me know what errors are you getting.

Comment: I did a clean and rebuild and nothing has changed.  These are the following errors I see: cannot find symbol class RecyclerView, LayoutManager, LinearLayoutManager; package RecyclerView does not exist,

Comment: Thanks! Importing the library sorted the issue for me. The '21' in the version number indicates the minimum SDK version supported by the app, ensure it's changed to the relevant SDK version - compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:**21**.0.+'

Comment: Maybe you forget to add maven repository, because I forgot

Answer (score 11):

For the latest version of Android Studio 3:

Find your gradle file under Gradle Scripts, build.gradle (Module)

Add dependency:

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.+'

}
```

Sync your gradle file (File / Sync Project with gradle files).

Go back to your code and hit ALT+Enter on the missing reference.

That should be it.

Answer (score 3):

After updating Gradle to 4.4

I find that my import is complaining about the RecyclerView

it turns out that I no longer need to import separate RecyclerView dependency

Previously:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
```

After update:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

On Android Studio 3.2.1, build on October 8 2018, for a new project, all I need is to add

`implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"`

in app build.gradle. The support_version is the same as the one in appcompat-v7 generated by New Project wizard.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works:

1. Add the dependency
2. Clean and rebuild the project

Back to main-activity in red error **press** *alt+enter* 
android suggest to import library and it works. This was not there before clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

For API 28 or higher:

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
```

Maybe this helps someone.